# Lighthouse testing with postGraphQL fails when using subscriptions

Tags: phpunit, graphql-subscriptions, laravel-lighthouse

I have a laravel package which uses GraphQL (Lighthouse) to extend my base project(s). Everything works fine when adding my package and doing queries etc.

But since I try to make a *postGraphQL* request within my testing file, where the given query or mutation utilizes the *@broadcast* Directive, the request fails saying:

```
Add the SubscriptionServiceProvider to your config/app.php to enable subscriptions.
```

The `SubscriptionServiceProvider` is added to providers array of *app config* when booting the test environment. I use orchestra/testbench and add the provider within the `getEnvironmentSetUp` method.

But I think that the generated *postGraphQL* request doesn't have the `SubscriptionServiceProvider` added.
I traced it back to the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequest` class which creates a new *kernel* object that does the request and doesn't seem to boot up as it should.

Maybe the problem is me being within a laravel package and not in a "regular" laravel project, where one would define the `SubscriptionServiceProvider` within *config/app.php*.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Anybody here who had this problem as well? I couldn't find anything here or googling around unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! 
Instead of trying to add the *SubscriptionServiceProvider* to the app environment using the `getEnvironmentSetUp` method of orchestra I now add it within the method `getPackageProviders` together with the *LighthouseServiceProvider* like so:

```
protected function getPackageProviders($app)
{
    return [
        LighthouseServiceProvider::class,
        SubscriptionServiceProvider::class,
        MyOwnPackageProvider::class,
    ];
}
```

And it works like a charm :)